# Describe ELB AWS security group rules by SG name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to use Python boto3 to describe ELB SecurityGroup and list all it's rules.

However, there is an error saying that I am not using default VPC.

I try to filter and specify non-default VPC vpc-67890, but it doesn't help:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_security_groups(
     ...: Filters = [
     ...: {
     ...: 'Name': 'vpc-id',
     ...: 'Values': [
     ...: 'vpc-67890']},
     ...: ],
     ...: GroupNames=['SG_NAME'])

ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: The security group 'SG_NAME' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-12345'
```

I tried using boto3 Resource, but it's the same problem and it doesn't return all SecurityGroups, just empty response:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
vpc = ec2.Vpc('vpc-67890')
all_security_groups = vpc.security_groups.all()
specific_security_group = vpc.security_groups.filter(GroupNames=['SG_NAME'])

for i in all_security_groups:
    print i
```

(no response)

When I query for specific group which I filtered, it throws an error:

```
for i in specific_security_group:
    print i

ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: The security group 'SG_NAME' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-12345'
```

I am aware that it requires GroupID instead of GroupName if non-default VPC is being used, but the problem is that describe_elb API returns only GroupName.

The same is happening when trying to describe SecurityGroup via AWS Cli:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-names SG_NAME

An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: The security group 'SG_NAME' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-12345'
```

Anyone having the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't use the GroupName parameter outside the default VPC. It is a bit buried in the API docs: [describing the GroupName parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSecurityGroups.html#API_DescribeSecurityGroups_RequestParameters) it says:

> `[EC2-Classic and default VPC only]`

You need to leave the "query by group" part empty and instead use the group in the filter, like this:

```
filters = [dict(Name='group-name', Values=['SG_NAME']), 
           dict(Name='vpc-id', Values=['vpc-67890'])]
client.describe_security_groups(Filters=filters)
```